# Login With React Native using Asyncronous storage

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am implementing login in React Native using Asynchronous storage. Here, when users login successfully, i keep the user object in the Asynchronous storage then i access this information to get the Authentication Key for my API request anytime I want to do a request. 
When I login and information is stored in the Asynchronous storage, the current app session fails to get the just stored information hence all my authenticated request fails in this session. When I close the app and restart, I can successfully get the information from the Async storage stored in the previous session and make successful authenticated request.

I do not know what I am missing out in my code as I believe I need to refresh or reload the app internally after a successful login but I do not know how to do this in React Native. Any information or help is needed. Here is my Login code.

```
HttpRequest.post('api/login', body)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson.succcode == 201){  //successful login
          var data = responseJson.user;
          data.loggedIn = true;
           AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_DATA, JSON.stringify(data)).then(val => {
                  console.log('just before reload in login')
                  Actions.menu(); //this solves the after login problem as it goes to the next page only after a successful AsyncStorage save
                  this.setState({ procesing: false });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.setState({ procesing: false, error: "Couldn't log you in! Please try again" });
                    //console.log("\nCouldn't save to AsyncStorage: " + err + "\n");
                });
            }
            else{
                 this.setState({ procesing: false, error: "Wrong Username and/or Password! Please try again" });
            }
```

After I have login, my request looks like ;

```
//for making a post request
    post:  (url,body) => {
        return fetch(url+'?access-token='+this.state.user.auth_key, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Autorization': 'Bearer token2'
            },
        })
```

but the user object is gotten from the Async storage as

```
getUser(){
  return AsyncStorage.getItem("USER_DATA").then(value => {
        if(JSON.parse(value) == null) {
           return false;

        } else {
            return JSON.parse(value)
        }
    });
 },
```

Any Information, Ideas, proposed solutions are highly welcome

Comment: Can you share the complete code??

Comment: Maneesh. it is in different files according to the structure. I do not know what exactly you cant find in the code. because i have a complete file that handles login, another one that I use to sent request , another helpers file etc all of this handling different things

Comment: Where are u calling `getUser() function`?

Comment: I am calling the getUser() in my request component and I set the data gotten from it into this.state.user thats why you can see me use this.state.user.auth_key

Comment: Before `setState` value have u checked the value in `console`?

Comment: which setState ?? like I said earlier, I can not get the data from Async until I reload the app. When I reload the app, I can get the information but when the app is not reloaded, I do not get it

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the information correctly, you can pass the information to the next screen or use the asynchronous repository as it is now.

> **If use navigation**

```js
HttpRequest.post('api/login', body)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson.succcode == 201){  //successful login
          var data = responseJson.user;
          data.loggedIn = true;
           this.setState({ procesing: false });
           this.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen",{data: JSON.stringify(data) })
            }
            else{
                 this.setState({ procesing: false, error: "Wrong Username and/or Password! Please try again" });
            }
```

**LoginScreen**

```js
this.state={
     data : this.props.navigation.state.params.data
}
```

> **If use AsyncStorge**

```js
HttpRequest.post('api/login', body)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson.succcode == 201){  //successful login
          var data = responseJson.user;
          data.loggedIn = true;
           AsyncStorage.setItem("USER_DATA", JSON.stringify(data));
           this.setState({ procesing: false });
            else{
                 this.setState({ procesing: false, error: "Wrong Username and/or Password! Please try again" });
            }
```

LoginScreen

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("USER_DATA")

   }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The issue with passing it as props is because I have so many pages in my application and i won't want to be passing the props through out the entire application.

Comment: For AsncStorage, I have done that but I do not still get a success after the first time of login which means when I login, and set the data into AsyncStorage, I can not get it till I close that session of the app and restart the app

Comment: If you store it on AsyncStorage, the data remains unless you erase it again.

Comment: exactly, I do not erase it but I can not access it in the same session when it was put. If I close the session, I am able to get the data in the next session

Comment: can I reload a react Native app internally without closing the app ??

Comment: It is only natural that the saved screen does not get the value. Unless the screen is rendered again when the value is stored, the value can be viewed on the next screen.

Comment: Yes the next screen does not even view the value. only the next render of the app reloads the app. And if that is the way it is suppose to be, how to I render the app internally

Comment: If you want to restart just the JS part, then you can use React Native Restart Package. This will work on both Android and iOS.